# metafor: use of annosym argument in addpoly()

Tags: r, metafor

I draw a forest plot with non-default `annosym` values:

```
res <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure = 'OR', method='DL',
       slab=paste(author, year))


forest(res, 
   annosym=c(' (','; ',')'),
   ylim=c(-2,16)
)
```

And try to add some sub-analysis results with the same `annosym` specification:

```
dat.bcg.rand <- dat.bcg[dat.bcg$alloc=='random',]

res.rand <- rma.uni(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg.rand, measure = 'OR', method='DL', 
                            slab=paste(author, year))

addpoly(res.rand, mlab='Random alloc.',atransf=exp, annosym=c(' (','; ',')'))
```

to see a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In text.default(...) : "annosym" is not a graphical parameter
2: In segments(...) : "annosym" is not a graphical parameter
3: In segments(...) : "annosym" is not a graphical parameter
4: In segments(...) : "annosym" is not a graphical parameter
5: In polygon(...) : "annosym" is not a graphical parameter
6: In text.default(...) : "annosym" is not a graphical parameter
```

and a plot that mixes two `annosym` specifications:

[image]

Do you have any workarounds for this? I really, really need to change default `annosym`s in `addpoly()`.

Comment: Seems like I didn't implement `annosym` for `addpoly()` yet. Let me get on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why I forgot to implement `annosym` in `addpoly.default()` and `addpoly.rma()` but this has now been added. So if you grab the 'development' version of `metafor` as described here:

https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor#installation

then it should work.

One other issue if you add polygons like this: The alignment is off because less space is needed for the annotations corresponding to that last polygon. You can use:

```
addpoly(res.rand, mlab='Random alloc.', atransf=exp, annosym=c(' (','; ',')'), width=c(5,5,5))
```

(or just `width=5`) to fix this (note that `-0.75` consists of 5 characters). The alignment will still be slightly off because by default a non-fixed-width font is used for the text. If you combine this with `fonts="mono"` in both `forest()` and `addpoly()`, then the alignment will be right. You can also use other fonts than the default fixed-width font to make this look nicer and/or only a fixed-width font for the annotations (`fonts` can take two values).